# Convert json object to java object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a request like that:

```
   let jsonData= {};
   jsonData["className"]= className;
   jsonData["models"]= arr;
   let endPoint= "/classses?classAndModel=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringfy(jsonData));
return $.ajax({
            url: host + endPoint,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            method: "POST"
        });
```

I want to convert that json to java object.I tried this one

```
My rest service is: 

@PostMapping(value=/classes",consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> addClassAndModelMapping(ClassAndModels classAndModels){

}


public class ClassAndModels {
   ClassAndModelResult classAndModel;

   ...getter and setter...
  }
public ClassAndModelResult {
    String className;
    List<String> models;

    ...getter and setters...
 }
```

I get 400 error.If I change that line  `ClassAndModelResult classAndModel` to  `String classAndResult`.I get response but I want Object type.Do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What does the JSON you are submitting look like? Have you tried creating an instance of `ClassAndModels` and serialising it to JSON to see how it compares to the JSON you are passing in?

Comment: You are using `@PostMapping` annotations. Looks like you are running a Spring (Boot) application, is this correct?

Comment: @smichel yes it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of code shows that you are sending data as a query string.

Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

But considering the @PostMapping, you should send that data in the request body and do something like this on the server side.

```
@PostMapping("/classes")
public ResponseEntity<Void> addClassAndModelMapping(@RequestBody ClassAndModels classAndModels){
 //
}
```

As Phils says, you can add a GetMapping on your controller to see how your ClassAndModels its being serialized

Source: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

P.S. Sorry about my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Yes.Data is being sending as query string.I will add @RequestBody annotation

Comment: Can I use query string and @RequestBody together?

Comment: @sneijder10 yes. Try something like public ResponseEntity<Void> addClassAndModelMapping(@RequestBody ClassAndModels classAndModels, @RequestParam(required = false) String testParam). This way you can send http://host:port/api/classes?testParam=XXXXXXX and the json on the request body

Comment: @sneijder10    on ajax part, try `dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',` and also set `data: jsonData`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add @RequestParam annotation or better use classAndModel value as RequestBody similar to the below.And also correct the spelling mistake in the javascript url.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/classes")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addClassAndModelMapping(@RequestBody ClassAndModels modal) {
}
```

Comment: Did you correct that spelling mistake mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Please use application/json in consumes

Comment: Please send that json data along with complete request

Comment: Also I tried this one  @RequestMapping(value = "/classes", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")